# Convergence for a Random Normal Process defined by Recursion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, random-functions

A question from my Random Processes exams:

Let $ W_0,W_1,W_2,...$ be a sequence of independent Gaussian random variables with **Mean** 0 and **Variance** $ \sigma ^ 2 > 0 $.

Define the sequence $ (X_n : n \geq 0) $ recursively by $ X_0 = 0 $ and $ X_{k+1} = \frac{X_k + W_k}{2}$.
Determine whether the sequence $(X_n)$ converges in each
of the four senses, namely mean square, almost sure, probability and distribution.

My work:

$$ X_1 = \frac{W_0}{2}$$
$$ X_2 = \frac{W_1 + X_1}{2} = \frac{W_0}{2^2} + \frac{W_1}{2}$$

Thus,

$$X_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{W_k}{2^{n-k}}}$$

Now, how to utilise the fact that these are $\pmb{i.i.d. RV's}$ and get to different convergences?

Sum of Normal $\pmb{i.i.d. RV's}$ Normal.

Thus, $\mu(X_n) = 0$

Also,
$$Var(X_n) = Var\bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{W_k}{2^{n-k}}}\bigr)=\bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{Var(W_k)}{4^{n-k}}}\bigr)$$

$$Var(X_n) = \sigma ^ 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{4^{n-k}}} = \sigma ^ 2 \bigl( \frac{\frac{1}{4}(1-\frac{1}{4^n})}{1-\frac{1}{4}} \bigr)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} Var(X_n) = \frac{\sigma ^ 2}{3}
$$

How, to move forward with this?

Comment: Do you know what the distribution for a sum of iid normal rv is?

Comment: Can you find the distribution and mean and variance of $X_n$?  For example $X_1$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{4}$

Comment: Thanks @lonzaleggiera. Made the correction.

Comment: 1) Almost Sure Convergence: $$\Bbb P \Bigl (\ \omega \ | \lim_{n\to \infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \Bigr) = 1$$

2) Convergence in Probability: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bbb P \Bigl ( |X_n - X| > \epsilon \Bigr) = 0$$

3) Convergence in Mean Squared Sense: $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \Bbb E \bigl [ (X_n-X)^2 \bigr] = 0$$

4. Convergence in Distribution: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your variance computation. If you know the mean and variance of each of the normal rv $X_n$, then by Lévy's convergence theorem you can use the pointwise convergence of their characteristic functions to show that the sequence converges in distribution to a normal rv $X$. Then you can compute $E[(X-X_n)^2]$ to show convergence in quadratic mean, which implies convergence in probability.

Comment: @Joe Could you please elaborate how to move forward in proving $E[(X-X_n)^2]$ convergence. Because $E[X_n ^2] = \frac{\sigma ^ 2 }{3}$ and here X=$\mu(X_n)$=0

Comment: By the same argument above, $X - X_n$ is a normal rv with a variance that you can find using the same computations. Instead of starting the sum at $i=0$, the sum would start at $i=n$.

Comment: But for $Var(X-X_n) = Var(X) - Var(X_n)$. They need to be independent. How could that be proven? Also, X~$N(0,\frac{\sigma ^ 2}{3})$ right??

Comment: They definitely are not independent. I originally thought your sequence was $X_n = \sum_i^{n-1} W_i/2^i$. Now that I see its $X_n = \sum_i^{n-1} W_i/2^{n-i}$, I don’t think it does converge in qm, but I’m not sure without writing it out. I’d trying writing out the formula for $X_m-X_n$ for $m>n$, in terms of $W_i$, and taking the limit as $m\to \infty$ to see what the variance of $X-X_n$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown that $\ \big(X_n\big)\ $ converges in distribution to $\ \mathscr{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{3}\right)\ $.  Since almost sure convergence and convergence in mean square both imply convergence in probability, then if you can show that $\ \big(X_n\big)\ $ *doesn't* converge in probability, as I believe you can, then it can't converge almost surely or in mean square either.

Suppose $\ \big(X_n\big)\ $ converges in probability to $\ X\ $.  Then, for any positive integers, $\ m,n\ $, and any positive real $\ \epsilon\ $,
\begin{align}
P\big(|X-X_m|>\epsilon\big)&=P\big(|X_n-X_m-(X_n-X)|>\epsilon\big)\\
&\ge P\big(|X_n-X_m|-|X_n-X|>\epsilon\big)\\
&\ge P\big(\{|X_n-X_m|>2\epsilon\}\setminus \{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\}\big)\\
&\ge P\big(|X_n-X_m|>2\epsilon)-P\big(|X_n-X|>\epsilon\big)\ .
\end{align}

Since $\ W_0, W_1,\dots, W_n, \dots\ $ are independent normal, then $\ X_n-X_m\ $ is normal with mean $0$ and variance
\begin{align}
&\hspace{1em}Var\big(X_n\big)+Var\big(X_m\big)-2E(X_nX_m)\\
&=\frac{\sigma^2\left(1-4^{-n}\right)}{3}+\frac{\sigma^2\left(1-4^{-m}\right)}{3}-\frac{\sigma^2\left(1-4^{-\min(m,n)}\right)}{2^{m+n-1}3}\\\
&\ge\frac{\sigma^2}{3}
\end{align}
for all $\ m, n\ $.
Under the supposition that $\ \big(X_n\big)\ $ converges in probability to $\ X\ $, there must exist a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that $\ P\big(|X_N-X|>\frac{\sigma}{2\sqrt{3}}\big)<1-\mathscr{N}(0,1)(1)\ $. Then for any$\ m\ $, we have from above that
\begin{align}
P\bigg(|X-X_m|>\frac{\sigma}{2\sqrt{3}}\bigg)&\ge P\left(|X_N-X_m|>\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-P\left(|X_N-X|>\frac{\sigma}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\\
&\ge P\left(|X_N-X_m|>\sqrt{Var\big(X_N-X_m\big)}\right)\\
&\hspace{2em}-\big(1-\mathscr{N}(0,1)(1)\big)\\
&=1-\mathscr{N}(0,1)(1)\ ,
\end{align}
from which it follows that $\ \big(X_n\big)\ $ does *not* converge in probability to $\ X\ $, thus contradicting the original assumption that it did.